# document.getElementsByName returns undefined

Tags: html, flask, model-view-controller

I am new to python flask and MVC.

I am trying to print out the selected option in the dropdown list.

This is my list in .py function.

```
@app.route('/', methods=['GET'])
def dropdown2():
    model2 = [
        {'id': '1', 'quarter': 'Q1'},
        {'id': '2', 'quarter': 'Q2'},
        {'id': '3', 'quarter': 'Q3'},
        {'id': '4', 'quarter': 'Q4'}
             ]
```

This is my base.html code.

```
            </div>
            <select name= quarters method="GET" action="/" onchange="myFunction3()">
                {% for m2 in model2 %}
                <option value= "{{m2.quarter}}" SELECTED>{{ m2.quarter }}</option>"
                {% endfor %}
            </select>
```

```
            <p name="quarters"></p>
            function myFunction3() {
              var x = document.getElementsByName("quarter"s).value;
              document.getElementsByName("quarters").innerHTML = "<span style='color: blue;'>Period: </span>" + x;
            }
```

Currently, it returns my innerHTML and undefined.
E.g. Period: Undefined

Any help will be appreciated, thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of:

```
<select name= quarters
<option value= "{{m2.quarter}}" SELECTED>{{ m2.quarter }}</option>"
```

do:

```
<select name="quarters"
<option value="{{m2.quarter}}" selected>{{ m2.quarter }}</option>
```

The first is incorrectly defined attribute. Attributes on elements must have this format: `attributeName="value"`.

Instead of:

```
var x = document.getElementsByName("quarter"s).value;
```

Do:

```
let quarters = document.getElementsByName("quarters")
let quarter = quarters[0];
let x = quarter.value;
```

`getElementsByName` returns a list so you need to extract the element first;